# C# Error loading files with full stops / periods in the file name

Tags: c#, csv

When loading a file with `.`'s in (`15.01.19.csv`) I am getting the following error:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: ''15.01.19.csv' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.'

On line:

```
adapter.Fill(dataTable);
```

Of code:

```
private DataTable FillData(string connection, string query)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connection))
    {
        con.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        adapter.Dispose();
    };
    return dataTable;
}
```

The code to bring in  the file is:

```
private DataTable GetData(string userFileName)
{
    string dirName = Path.GetDirectoryName(userFileName);
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(userFileName);
    string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(userFileName);
    string connection = string.Empty;
    string query = string.Empty;

    switch (fileExtension)
    {
        case ".csv":
            connection = $@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={dirName};" +
                           "Extended Properties=\"text; HDR=Yes; IMEX=1; FMT=Delimited\"";
            query = $"SELECT * FROM {fileName}";
            break;
    }
    return FillData(connection, query);       
}
```

I tried adding a regex to the string `dirName = Path.GetDirectoryName(userFileName);` but this didn't work.

Comment: Try to use Square Brackets when selecting like `SELECT * FROM [{fileName}]`, or you can get the ShortFileName

Comment: @GopeshSharma Still the same error unfortunately

Comment: You can try to get the ShortFileName just run `dir /x` from cmd to find out if there is any ShortName of your file, if there is use that.

Comment: Can you just rename the file or make a copy with a valid name?

Comment: @Crowcoder Not really, it will be used to process a lot of files so I am trying to find a solution that does it on the fly

Comment: @Matt I meant in code, not manually. Possibly rename it to something compliant then change it back when finished processing?

Comment: @Crowcoder I have tried putting `new Regex("([!@#$%^&*()]|(?:[.](?![a-z0-9]+$)))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Replace(userFileName, "_");
            userFileName = userFileName.Replace(".", "");`In the GetData code but it wasn't working as required.

Comment: @Matt I meant rename the file on disk, not just change the string you pass in. If you do that it won't matter what you name it so you don't need a complex and error prone regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by adding the following code:

```
string userFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(userFileNameUT), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(userFileNameUT.Replace(".", "")) + ".csv");
File.Copy(userFileNameUT, userFileName, true);
```

To my `Browse` button click:

```
private void Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userFileNameUT = string.Empty;
    using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        ofd.RestoreDirectory = true;
        ofd.Filter = "CSV Files|*.csv|Excel '97-2003|*.xls|Excel 2007-2019|*.xlsx";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            userFileNameUT = ofd.FileName;
    }
    string userFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(userFileNameUT), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(userFileNameUT.Replace(".", "")) + ".csv");
    File.Copy(userFileNameUT, userFileName, true);
    if (userFileNameUT.Length == 0) return;
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = GetData(userFileName);
    fileTextBox.Text = userFileName;
}
```